# MySQL logic for prioritizing matching pattern/text

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table of incidents that have a short_description.  I'm trying to assign them to a category based on the text in that short_description (not ideal, I know, but I'm working with an existing system and don't have much control).  So I created a lookup table with search_text to look for, and the category value that should be assigned to the incident.  In some cases more than one search_text value matches the short_description.  I want to use the priority field to choose the highest priority (lowest priority value, such as 1) when this happens.  I feel like maybe this involves a window function or something, but I'm not sure how to approach it.

Can someone help me with the changes needed in the logic below?

Thanks!

---

The query below returns two results, but I want it to just return one (Cluster) because Cluster is priority 1, and Disk is priority 2.  I only want one record per snumber (incident).

```
CREATE TABLE snow_incident_s_2 (
  SNUMBER varchar(40) DEFAULT NULL,
  SHORT_DESCRIPTION varchar(200) DEFAULT NULL
);

INSERT INTO snow_incident_s_2 (snumber, short_description) values ('INC15535802','Prognosis::ADMINCLUSTER [5251]::CmaDiskPartitionNearFull, PROGNOSIS:ADMINCLUSTER');

CREATE TABLE lkp_incident_category_2 (
  incident_category_id smallint(6) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  incident_type varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  category varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  search_text varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  priority smallint(6) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (incident_category_id)
);

INSERT INTO lkp_incident_category_2 (incident_type, category, search_text, priority) values ('INC','Cluster','Cluster',1);
INSERT INTO lkp_incident_category_2 (incident_type, category, search_text, priority) values ('INC','Disk','Disk',2);

SELECT 
    inc.snumber,
    inc.short_description,
    ic.search_text,
    ic.category
FROM
    snow_incident_s_2 inc
        LEFT JOIN
    lkp_incident_category_2 ic ON inc.short_description LIKE CONCAT('%', ic.search_text, '%')
        AND ic.incident_type = 'INC'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

window functions don't exist in mysql.  but you can mimic them using variables.

I have been trying to test this but sqlfiddle is not cooperating so here is what I believe should work for you give it a try.

```
SELECT *
FROM (
  SELECT 
      inc.snumber
      ,inc.short_description
      ,ic.search_text
      ,ic.category
      ,(@rownum := IF(@incnum=inc.snumber,@rownum+1,1)) as IncidentRowNum
      ,@incnum := inc.snumber
  FROM
      snow_incident_s_2 inc
      LEFT JOIN lkp_incident_category_2 ic
      ON inc.short_description LIKE CONCAT('%', ic.search_text, '%')
      AND ic.incident_type = 'INC'
      CROSS JOIN (SELECT @rownum := 0, @incnum := '') var
  ORDER BY
    ic.priority
) t
WHERE
 t.IncidentRowNum = 1
;
```

Fully tested and functional here is a sqlfiddle of it http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/75ff1/7

Comment: Ok, I have a list of probably 100 different categories.  The minimum value for a matching search_text may not be 1.  It could be 5 and 30.  In that case I would want 5.

Comment: yeah that's what that should do is it not?  You can take off the outer query and look at IncidentRowNum to see what rownumber it is assigning to which match.  IncidentRowNum is a generated rownumber based on order of priority but is not the same value as the priority.

Comment: @mateoc15 FYI I tested it and it does what is desired. I put a sql fiddle link in the answer for you

Comment: I see, rownum not priority explicitly.  Works for me.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Here is how to use a window function.

I have to say  `ON inc.short_description LIKE CONCAT('%', ic.search_text, '%')` will be slow.   If this is is done once a while (like every day) as an ad-hoc it will be fine, but if this is done often (every hour, every minute or more often) you'll want to materialize the existence of these values since you can't make an index for them unless you use full a text query or NOSQL solution.

```
SELECT snumber, short_description, search_text, category
FROM (
  SELECT snumber, short_description, search_text, category,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (partition by snumber order by priority asc) as rn
  FROM (
    SELECT 
      inc.snumber,
      inc.short_description,
      ic.search_text,
      ic.category,
      ic.priority
    FROM snow_incident_s_2 inc
    LEFT JOIN lkp_incident_category_2 ic 
      ON inc.short_description LIKE CONCAT('%', ic.search_text, '%') 
      AND c.incident_type = 'INC'
  ) X
) Y
WHERE RN = 1
```

Comment: why not put the row number in the inner most query?  also he tagged and noted mysql

Comment: @Matt - he asked about windowing functions specifically -- I think it is easier to understand written this way.  Then I noticed the mysql, but I figured -- he asked for a windowing function example so I'll leave it in case he actually did want it.